# Angular login request

Tags: angular, request, angular7

I'm new to Angular and want to build a login. But I don't know how to make a login request. I searched for similar question but only found older ones. Thank you for the help

**My Form:**

```
 <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup" (submit)="firstForm()" class="formLogin">
  <mat-form-field class="formFieldName">
    <input matInput placeholder="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>person</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="password" type="password" formControlName="password">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>lock</mat-icon>

  </mat-form-field>
  <div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="loginButton">Log in</button>
    <div>
      <mat-icon class="iconHelp">help_outline</mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Logincomponent.ts**

```
 firstForm() {
     if (this.firstFormGroup.valid) {
        console.log(this.firstFormGroup.value);
        console.log(this.loginUserData);
     } else {
         this.snackbar.open('Error!', null, {duration: 3000});
     }
 }
```

**Service:**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
sendData(user: any) {
    this.http.post('https://.../token', user, {withCredentials: true});
}
```

Best regards Lary

Comment: not sure if you are looking for a tutorial on how to build a login flow with angular or if you have a specific question regarding your login implementation?

Comment: use (ngSubmit) instead of submit it will work and put button type submit

Comment: @O.MeeKoh I searched for a solution for my login problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

In service

```
sendData(user: any)  {
    return this.http.post('https://.../token', user);
}
```

Logincomponent.ts

```
constructor(private serviceName:ServiceName){}

firstForm() {
   if (this.firstFormGroup.invalid) {
      this.snackbar.open('Error!', null, {duration: 3000});
      return;
   } 
   this.serviceName.sendData(this.firstFormGroup.getRawValue())
   .subscribe((response: any) => {
       console.log("On response");
   },error => {
       console.log("On error");
   })
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.